# Python - The two-dimensional (2D) intensity histogram of image

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

i want to show 2d histogram of figure but i don't know which function support in opencv or matplotlib .  Please let me know which function, thanks everyone.
I want to display results that look like thí
[Thế describe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfuvZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow.  Please share your input image and some data from you need to get your expected output.

Comment: Your image is not a 2D histogram! It is simply a grayscale image with a color heat map applied.  Please explain better and show a proper example of what you want.

Comment: since i don't know what mode the image i see is displayed in, at first i thought it was 2d but maybe like you said it shows a heat chart

Comment: Can you tell me if there is a function that supports the display of heat graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Both opencv and numpy contain implementations to compute image histograms. See [opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d0d/tutorial_py_2d_histogram.html) for reference.

Here's a quick example of how to use opencv to compute a 2D histogram with your image.

- Convert the image to HSV space
- Use opencv calcHist to compute the 2D histogram between the Hue and Saturation

  - Hue ranges from 0-180
  - Saturation ranges from 0-256
- Convert the Histogram to HSV color and display

Here's the resulting Histogram:
[image: HSV Histogram]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read image
image = cv2.imread(r"path\to\image")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# compute 2D histograms in HSV space
hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [0, 1], None, [180, 256], [0, 180, 0, 256])

# get HSV map to display histogram in HSV color
hsv_map = np.zeros((180, 256, 3), np.uint8)
h, s = np.indices(hsv_map.shape[:2])
hsv_map[:,:,0] = h
hsv_map[:,:,1] = s
hsv_map[:,:,2] = 255
hsv_map = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_map, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# rescale and convert to HSV space
hist_scale = 10
hist = np.clip(hist*0.005*hist_scale, 0, 1)
vis = hsv_map*hist[:,:,np.newaxis] / 255.0

# display
plt.imshow(vis)
plt.title("HSV Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Saturation")
plt.ylabel("Hue")
plt.show();
```

You can also make histograms along pairs of color channels like so:

```
# Blue Green histogram (opencv reads images as BGR)
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0,1], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])
```

Sources:

- https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d0d/tutorial_py_2d_histogram.html
- http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/opencv/histogram_2d_demo.html
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/samples/python/color_histogram.py

Comment: Thank you for sharing this useful information, glad to help you